# A couple lines of javasript to format currency

Tags: javascript

I m using this function:

```
function formatMoney(amount, decimalCount = 2, decimal = ",", thousands = ".") {
    try {
        decimalCount = Math.abs(decimalCount);
        decimalCount = isNaN(decimalCount) ? 2 : decimalCount;

        const negativeSign = amount < 0 ? "-" : "";

        let i = parseInt(amount = Math.abs(Number(amount) || 0).toFixed(decimalCount)).toString();
        let j = (i.length > 3) ? i.length % 3 : 0;

        return negativeSign + (j ? i.substr(0, j) + thousands : '') + i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + thousands) + (decimalCount ? decimal + Math.abs(amount - i).toFixed(decimalCount).slice(2) : "");
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
};
```

when I try to get a number works good until `1,000.01`.  The `999.99` with a `console.log` returns the `999.00`. The format that I need is `111,111.11 (thousands, hundreds, decimals)`, when I try get a number higher than `999.99` I always get a no sense negative number.

Could someone please  explain where is my error?

Thanks.

```
var tmp1 = $('.'+auctionId2+' .productValue').html();
                                tmp1 = tmp1.replace(',', '@');
                                tmp1 = tmp1.replace('.', ',');
                                tmp1 = tmp1.replace('@', '.');
                                tmp1 = parseFloat(tmp1);
                                tmp1 = tmp1 - bid_price;
                                var tmp2 = formatMoney(tmp1);
                                $('.'+auctionId2+' .auctionSavings').html(tmp2 + "€");
```

If i do a console.log before the parseFloat it give me good the number, if i do it after the parseFloat and its a number higher than 999.99 it give me a negative no sense number.

Comment: How you are invoking the function? Can you also add code where are calling the function.

Comment: yes of course, var tmp1 = $('.'+auctionId2+' .productValue').html();
        tmp1 = tmp1.replace(',', '@');
        tmp1 = tmp1.replace('.', ',');
        tmp1 = tmp1.replace('@', '.');
        tmp1 = parseFloat(tmp1);
        tmp1 = tmp1 - bid_price;
        var tmp2 = formatMoney(tmp1);
        $('.'+auctionId2+' .auctionSavings').html(tmp2 + "€");

Answer (score 1):

You can pass country code to toLocaleString method to get currency format

```js
const money = 10000;

console.log(money.toLocaleString('en-US', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'USD'
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing your custom code to format this, you can use the java-script prototype method.

```
var n = 999999.99
n.toLocaleString()
"999,999.99"
```

Comment: Nice workaround for a part of his problem, but it doesnt answer his specific question.